# GDrive token gets invalidated after some time

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth, google-drive-api

**Current Working Flow**

- I have a web app (developed in wordpress)
- I am using google-drive-sdk to upload dynamically generated pdf file to a GMail account.
- The GMail account has been configured in the web app giving the
  secret key ....
- The web app first makes the authentication ===>i.e The GDrive Account is authenticated for the first time by the GMail owner (In Google Permission window the button *Allow Access* is clicked)
- It works fine thereafter when called from the web app - the pdf file dynamically generated gets into the configured GDrive

**The Problem**

PDF files gets uploaded to the GDrive only for some time.

After sometime it doesn't upload the files to GDrive.
I then tried creating a new token - It again starts uploading files but stops after some time.

This happens only in Staging server.

In my local development system it keeps working fine - uploading the file to GDrive whenever the app is executed.

The difference between both the environment is the GMail Account is different.

If you have any idea on the cause of issue or any pointers would really be helpful for me.

Comment: you need to create refresh token. The access token allowed one time.

Comment: All access tokens expire after 1 hour.

Comment: follow the official oauth guide in the drive docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth) to authorize requests. All requests to the Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

The details of the authorization process, or "flow," for OAuth 2.0 vary somewhat depending on what kind of application you're writing. The following general process applies to all application types:

- When you create your application, you register it using the Google API Console. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
- Activate the Drive API in the Google API Console. (If the API isn't listed in the API Console, then skip this step.)
- When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular *scope* of access.
- Google displays a *consent screen* to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
- If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
- Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
- If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

Some flows include additional steps, such as using *refresh tokens* to acquire new access tokens. For detailed information about flows for various types of applications, see [Google's OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).